# What permissions should wallet.dat have to be as secure as possible and still work?

Tags: security, wallet.dat

I would like to restrict the permissions on my `wallet.dat` file but but I don't want to stop the `bitcoind daemon` from functioning.

What are the bear minimum permissions that need to be on `wallet.dat` to make it functional, while making it as secure as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bare minimum permission would be to have it owned, and only accessible to, a user you specially create for bitcoind. At least for creation, and addition of new addresses for change, it will need to be not only readable but also writable. I am not sure if you can make it non-writable for as long as you have not exhausted the unused addresses in it.

Comment: so I could do `chmod 600 wallet.dat` and everything would work fine?

Comment: I believe so, yes.